# 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' does not contain a definition for

Tags: c#, json, linq

I have the following JSON:

```
{
    "ok": true,
    "resp": [
        {
            "aaa": 111,
            "bbb": "xyz",
            "ccc": [
                {...},
                {
                    "ddd": "hello",
                    "eee": 666,
                },
                {...}
            ],
            "read": false
        },
        {...},
        {...}
    ]
}
```

and this C# code:

```
dynamic my_obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(JSON);
var resps = my_obj.resp;
var x = ((IEnumerable<dynamic>)resps).Cast<dynamic>()
                            .Where(p => p.ccc.eee == 666).Count();
```

and below error:

```
'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' does not contain a definition for 'eee'.
```

I know, I could iterate through all elements in 'resps' and count elements, where element 'ccc.eee' equals 666, but is it possible to do it in one line with linq?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `ccc[1].eee`?

Comment: That's the answer, if you want to make it one @UlugbekUmirov

Comment: think OP has mistaken querying in memory obejct with MongoDB

Comment: Sometimes it is 1st, sometimes 2nd element that eee=666, so I cannot use ccc[0].eee or ccc[1].eee

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since `ccc` is array, you need to iterate over it.

Count number of eee=666:

```
int x = ((IEnumerable<dynamic>)resps).Sum(
            p => ((IEnumerable<dynamic>)p.ccc).Count(o => o.eee == 666));
```

Count number of objects in resp having at least one eee=666:

```
int x = ((IEnumerable<dynamic>)resps).Count(
            p => ((IEnumerable<dynamic>)p.ccc).Any(o => o.eee == 666));
```

Comment: Almost there.. Your answer counts number of "eee=666". Array 'ccc' can have more than one element where eee=666 (and I want to count it only once). I am looking for a number of objects in resps, where "eee=666"?

Comment: Thanks @Ulugbek. Works like a charm when you put ')' before '.Any'